# How to order content by FilePath in Hugo?

Tags: templates, hugo, static-site

I'm trying to order content based on the FilePath. I want the FilePath to take precedence over the link title. I'm creating a documentation site with tutorials that will have sequenced content. I'd like the file structure to match the sequence of the tutorial (e.g. 01_getting_started.md, 2_setup.md, etc). I'd prefer to rely on the file path naming instead of defining the sequence information twice (in the filepath and in the weight front matter).

https://gohugo.io/templates/lists/#order-content

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** [@Jura](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/explicitly-order-pages-by-file-path/18977/2?u=zwbetz) has an even more terse solution:

```
{{ range sort site.RegularPages "File.Path" }}
  {{ . }}
{{ end }}
```

---

Given the following content:

```
content/
├── 01_getting_started.md
├── 02_setup.md
└── 03_configuration.md
```

Then this template code:

```
{{ $pages := slice }}

{{ range site.RegularPages }}
  {{ $pages = $pages | append (dict "page" . "file_path" .File.Path) }}
{{ end }}

{{ range sort $pages "file_path" }}
  {{ .page }}
{{ end }}
```

Will output the pages, ordered by file path:

```
  Page(/01_getting_started.md)

  Page(/02_setup.md)

  Page(/03_configuration.md)
```

It works by creating an empty slice (aka an array). It loops through all pages, appending a dictionary (aka a map) of the page object and its file path to the slice. Then the slice is sorted by file path in ascending order, and looped through.

You can then treat `.page` like the usual `.`. So `.page.Title` would be equivalent to `.Title`.